# How to inject io-ts-types in morphic-ts summoner?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

Let's take the example:

```
import * as Summoner from '@morphic-ts/batteries/lib/summoner-ESBST';
export interface IAppEnv {}
const { summon, tagged } = summonFor<IAppEnv>({});

const ReplyEntry_ = summon((F) =>
  F.interface(
    {
      subject: F.string(),
      action: F.string(),
    },
    'ReplyEntry'
  )
);
```

I'd like to use `NumberFromString` from `io-ts-types` module instead of `F.string()`.

My questions:

1. Is there any way to do so?
2. Is there a way to extend `F` object with custom codecs?

I know that I can use some codecs from `io-ts-types` by refining them like this:

```
const NES = summon(F => F.refined(F.string(), NonEmptyString.is, 'NES'))
```

Perhaps there is a way to do so using `F.newtype`.
I can see the example in https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/blob/master/packages/morphic-io-ts-interpreters/test/io-ts-interpreter.spec.ts#L97

```
interface NT extends Newtype<{ readonly NT: unique symbol }, Date> {}
const NT = summon(F => F.newtype<NT>('NT')(F.date()))
```

But it seems it doesn't contain any type conversion logic and I have no idea where to put it.

Comment: One of the possible solution from @ssledorze: https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/issues/128#issuecomment-907696083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not familiar with the library so there might be a cleaner, less hacky way of doing this, but after I looked at the code of `@morphic-ts` I came up with this:

```
import { summonFor } from '@morphic-ts/batteries/lib/summoner-ESBST';
import { EqType, EqURI } from '@morphic-ts/eq-interpreters';
import { IOTSType, IoTsURI } from '@morphic-ts/io-ts-interpreters';
import { ShowType, ShowURI } from '@morphic-ts/show-interpreters';
import * as Num from 'fp-ts/Number';
import { NumberFromString } from 'io-ts-types';
import type { AlgebraUnion } from '@morphic-ts/batteries/lib/program';
import type { M } from '@morphic-ts/batteries/lib/summoner-ESBST';
import type { HKT, Kind, URIS } from '@morphic-ts/common/lib/HKT';
import type { AnyEnv } from '@morphic-ts/common/lib/config';
import type { Eq } from 'fp-ts/Eq';
import type { Show } from 'fp-ts/Show';
import type { Type } from 'io-ts';

const customIoTs = <A, O>(
  type: Type<A, O>,
  eq: Eq<A>,
  show: Show<A>
): (<Env extends AnyEnv>(F: AlgebraUnion<'HKT', Env>) => HKT<Env, O, A>) => {
  const ioTsInterp: Kind<IoTsURI, AnyEnv, O, A> = () => new IOTSType(type);
  const eqInterp: Kind<EqURI, AnyEnv, O, A> = () => new EqType(eq);
  const showInterp: Kind<ShowURI, AnyEnv, O, A> = () => new ShowType(show);

  return (<Env extends AnyEnv>(
    F: AlgebraUnion<URIS, Env>
  ): Kind<URIS, Env, O, A> =>
    F._F === IoTsURI
      ? ioTsInterp
      : F._F === EqURI
      ? eqInterp
      : F._F === ShowURI
      ? showInterp
      : ((): never => {
          throw new Error(`Unknown URI: ${F._F}`);
        })()) as <Env extends AnyEnv>(
    F: AlgebraUnion<'HKT', Env>
  ) => HKT<Env, O, A>;
};

interface IAppEnv {}
const { summon } = summonFor<IAppEnv>({});

const numberFromString = customIoTs(NumberFromString, Num.Eq, Num.Show);

// Usage

const Foo = summon(F => numberFromString(F));

Foo.type.decode('123'); // Right 123
Foo.type.decode('abc'); // Left [...]
Foo.eq.equals(Foo.build(1), Foo.build(1)); // true
Foo.show.show(Foo.build(1)); // '1'

const Bar = summon(F => F.interface({ num: numberFromString(F) }, 'Bar'));

Bar.strictType.decode({ num: '123' }); // Right { num: 123 }
Bar.strictType.decode({ num: 'abc' }); // Left [...]
Bar.eq.equals(Bar.build({ num: 1 }), Bar.build({ num: 1 })); // true
Bar.show.show(Bar.build({ num: 1 })); // '{ num: 1 }'
```

### Explanation

The ESBST summoner calls the function you pass into `summon` (`program`) multiple times with different ‘interpreters’ (the `F` in `summon(F => ...)`):

```
const { create, type } = program(modelIoTsNonStrictInterpreter<NonNullable<R>>())(env)
return {
  build: a => a,
  eq: program(modelEqInterpreter<NonNullable<R>>())(env).eq,
  show: program(modelShowInterpreter<NonNullable<R>>())(env).show,
  strictType: program(modelIoTsStrictInterpreter<NonNullable<R>>())(env).type,
  type,
  create
}
```

<sup>[`@morphic-ts/batteries/src/summoner-ESBST.ts`](https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/blob/2aa2b9b07ef0abdd6550690da38f185eb62a53e8/packages/morphic-batteries/src/summoner-ESBST.ts#L54-L62)</sup>

(By the way the `R` above is the generic parameter of `summonFor` (e.g. `IAppEnv`).)

The `modelIoTs(Non)StrictInterpreter`s for ‘primtive’s are defined here:

```
export const ioTsPrimitiveInterpreter = memo(
  <Env extends AnyEnv>(): ModelAlgebraPrimitive<IoTsURI, Env> => ({
    _F: IoTsURI,
    date: config => env => new IOTSType(iotsApplyConfig(config)(DateFromISOString, env, {})),
    boolean: config => env => new IOTSType(iotsApplyConfig(config)(t.boolean, env, {})),
    string: config => env => new IOTSType(iotsApplyConfig(config)(t.string, env, {})),
    number: config => env => new IOTSType(iotsApplyConfig(config)(t.number, env, {})),
    // some more omitted for brevity
```

<sup>[`@morphic-ts/io-ts-interpreters/src/model/primitives.ts`](https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/blob/2aa2b9b07ef0abdd6550690da38f185eb62a53e8/packages/morphic-io-ts-interpreters/src/model/primitives.ts#L125-L161)</sup>

The important part here is the `new IOTSType`. I don’t our `NumberFromString` would require any [configuration](https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts#configurable), so I skipped the `iotsApplyConfig` part in my implementation.

This is very similar for the `modelEqInterpreter` and `modelShowInterpreter`, except using `EqType` and `ShowType` respectively:

```
export const eqPrimitiveInterpreter = memo(
  <Env extends AnyEnv>(): ModelAlgebraPrimitive<EqURI, Env> => ({
    _F: EqURI,
    date: config => env =>
      new EqType(
        eqApplyConfig(config)(
          eq.contramap(eqNumber, (date: Date) => date.getTime()),
          env,
          {}
        )
      ),
    boolean: config => env => new EqType(eqApplyConfig(config)(eqBoolean, env, {})),
    string: config => env => new EqType(eqApplyConfig(config)(eqString, env, {})),
    number: config => env => new EqType(eqApplyConfig(config)(eqNumber, env, {})),
```

<sup>[`@morphic-ts/eq-interpreters/src/model/primitives.ts`](https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/blob/2aa2b9b07ef0abdd6550690da38f185eb62a53e8/packages/morphic-eq-interpreters/src/model/primitives.ts#L84-L123)</sup>

```
export const showPrimitiveInterpreter = memo(
  <Env extends AnyEnv>(): ModelAlgebraPrimitive<ShowURI, Env> => ({
    _F: ShowURI,
    date: config => env => new ShowType(showApplyConfig(config)({ show: (date: Date) => date.toISOString() }, env, {})),
    boolean: config => env => new ShowType(showApplyConfig(config)(showBoolean, env, {})),
    string: config => env => new ShowType(showApplyConfig(config)(showString, env, {})),
    number: config => env => new ShowType(showApplyConfig(config)(showNumber, env, {})),
```

<sup>[`@morphic-ts/show-interpreters/src/model/primitives.ts`](https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/blob/2aa2b9b07ef0abdd6550690da38f185eb62a53e8/packages/morphic-show-interpreters/src/model/primitives.ts#L87-L121)</sup>

Comment: The author of the lib `morphic-ts` doesn't recommend your solution.
More details on this: https://github.com/sledorze/morphic-ts/issues/128#issuecomment-909346650
I appreciate your time and it's good enough to be marked as an answer.
Thank you 